# Power BI - How do I get the Status correct based on the columns I add or remove

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, min, status

Am stuck in a situation that I cant seem to solve, still learning so would appreciate if you could tell me what am I doing wrong and how do I get this right? It seems simple, but not for me anymore.

Background:

ACME company sells products in various cities and I need to check if ACME is Cheaper, Same or Expensive in terms of pricing. The same product may be sold in 10 different stores in a city and we want to know:

1. How is ACME doing for each product by City or by Store and I
   calculate that as follows:

For each City:

- List all the instances of that one product (lets say that product was sold in 10 stores in Dallas,so 10 instances,which means we may have 10 different store prices
- Then return the minimum price of these 10 prices
- Compare this minimum price against the ACME price and determine whether the product is Cheap, Same or Expensive

Formula:

1. Measure to calculate min price = 1 Min Price = CALCULATE(MINX(Data,Data[Store Price]),ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Barcode],Data[City],Data[Match Type],Data[Store]))
2. Calculated Column to detrmine status = 2 Price Status = if(Data[ACME Price]<[1 Min Price],"Cheap",if(Data[ACME Price]=[1 Min Price],"Equal","Expensive"))

Problem to be solved:

- **Screenshot 1** - When i have stores listed along with City, then the formula should consider the Store column and give me minimum price per Store (basically it will do a row by row comparison as a a store will show only once per city) which is what its doing in the "Min Price" and also the status is correct

Screenshot 1 - With Stores
[[image: Screenshot 1 - With Stores[2]]

- **Screenshot 2** - When I remove stores, the "Min Price" column is showing the right minimum price for a product per city, however the Status is incorrect - for product ending 7572, both the status must be Equal and for product ending 3566, it should be Expensive

Screenshot 2 - Without Stores
[image: Screenshot 2 - Without Stores]

Can someone please advise what am I doing wrong? How do i get the status right when viewing by City?

Comment: Your issue is because you are using a calculated column for `2 Price Status`. Calculated columns are evaluated row-by-row when the data is loaded, so they will always have the same value for any particular row of the table, no matter which context they are evaluated in (e.g. regardless of whether you have a filter on Store active). Try changing  `2 Price Status` to be a measure (it will need to be reworked a bit to avoid the use of the row-context when getting `Data[ACME Price]`), or adding a second calculated column for per-city price status.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mankarse! When you say rework, would you be able to please point me what you mean by it

Comment: One way to rework `2 Price Status` to be a measure would be to wrap every reference to Data[ACME Price] in VALUES: `if(VALUES(Data[ACME Price])<[1 Min Price],"Cheap",if(VALUES(Data[ACME Price])=[1 Min Price],"Equal","Expensive"))`. This will work as long as the measure always evaluated in a context where there is exactly one distinct `[ACME Price]`. If not, you need to figure out what logic you want to apply if there is more than one `[ACME Price]`.

Comment: Thanks heaps again mate! I will try this first thing when am home! Much appreciated!

Comment: To clarify the `VALUES` use: A column name on its own (i.e. that is not a argument to a function that expects a column name such as `VALUES`) will only have meaning in a row-context (e.g. the row-context for each row in when adding a calculated column). `VALUES` takes a column name and returns the distinct values in that column as a single-column table. If a single-column, single-row table is used where a scalar value is expected, it is implicitly converted to a scalar value. If `VALUES` returns more than one row, this implicit conversion will fail and you will get an error at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Mankarse, will keep you posted on how i go.

Comment: Hi Mankarse, I tried using a calculated column to calculate min value and it just wouldnt show the right numbers.

Hoping for the following results:
With Stores
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwyaMf0gskynbZ8ruBn43hquvLNqxUZI/view

Without Stores
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VtsJRfAE-5Lw6AJ4amTQmtkoVGynwB8m

PBIX file link below:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=12E1eD1Gy88OUvmcalzO_e_mJ3rRKveGP

Comment: A calculated column for min value will have the same problem as a calculated column for  `2 Price Status`: it will be computed once for the table (row-by-row), rather than dynamically for the row of the visual.